# OpenId sites option ordering different in careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Whenever I try to login to any of the stackExchange sites (mostly Stackoverflow) it takes some time for the logo of the sites supporting OpenId to load completely(it maybe due to my slow internet speed), though I can see the square boxes. So even before the logo loads I click the 4th box which in most of the stackExchange site is the `log on with Yahoo` option.

I did the same (clicked the 4th box before logo appeared) for the `careers.stackoverflow.com` login page but it took me to 'Facebook' login page when I expected it to take me to the Yahoo page. Then I realized that `careers.stackoverflow.com` has the openId login sites options ordering different from other stackExchange sites.

Check the following pics[image]:[image]

This may sound silly but I had to bring this to notice of the `careers.stackoverflow.com` developers. Maybe having consistency across stackExchange sites structure will be helpful to many(will surely help speedy users like me).

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed some time in the past, the Facebook option now appears before Yahoo on both sites.